# Can these two methods be adjusted so that I only parse the command line once?

Tags: c++, mfc

I have two methods that I call in `InitInstance`:

```
void CMeetingScheduleAssistantApp::DetectCommandLineSwitches()
{
    LPWSTR* szArglist = nullptr;
    int iNumArgs = 0;
    szArglist = CommandLineToArgvW(GetCommandLine(), &iNumArgs);
    if (iNumArgs > 0 && szArglist != nullptr)
    {
        for (int iArg = 0; iArg < iNumArgs; iArg++)
        {
            CString strArg(szArglist[iArg]);
            int iDelim = strArg.Find(_T("="));
            if (iDelim != -1)
            {
                CString strParamName = strArg.Left(iDelim);
                CString strParamValue = strArg.Mid(iDelim + 1);
                if (strParamName.CollateNoCase(_T("/lang")) == 0)
                {
                    m_strPathLanguageResourceOverride.Format(_T("%sMeetSchedAssist%s.dll"),
                        (LPCTSTR)GetProgramPath(), (LPCTSTR)strParamValue.MakeUpper());

                    if (!PathFileExists(m_strPathLanguageResourceOverride))
                        m_strPathLanguageResourceOverride = _T("");
                }
            }
        }

        // Free memory allocated for CommandLineToArgvW arguments.
        LocalFree(szArglist);
    }
}

void CMeetingScheduleAssistantApp::DetectFileToOpenFromFileExplorer()
{
    CCommandLineInfo cmdInfo;

    m_bOpenFileFromFileExplorer = false;
    m_strFileToOpenFromFileExplorerPath = _T("");

    ParseCommandLine(cmdInfo);
    if (PathFileExists(cmdInfo.m_strFileName))
    {
        m_bOpenFileFromFileExplorer = true;
        m_strFileToOpenFromFileExplorerPath = cmdInfo.m_strFileName;
    }
}
```

Each parses the command line in a different way:

- `CommandLineToArgvW` / `GetCommandLine`
- `ParseCommandLine`

I don't want to combine the methods as they are doing distinct tasks. But is it possible to adjust the logic so that I only parse the command line once?

Comment: Obviously, you would have to pick one approach or the other (`CommandLineToArgW()` vs `ParseCommandLine()`) to gather up all of the command-line parameters and cache them somewhere that you can reuse them whenever needed.

Comment: Neither one is required. The command line has been parsed for you already during application startup. Microsoft's CRT implementation makes the parsed command line accessible from anywhere by providing the [__argc, __argv, __wargv](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/c-runtime-library/argc-argv-wargv) global variables.

Comment: @IInspectable Now you are taking me back to my MS-DOS days!

Comment: I still don't quite get how one decides if the argument in `__wargv` is a switch/value v a file (from File Explorer)

Comment: You can't. It's just an array of pointers to strings as passed on the command line. The semantics of those values are introduced by your application. [CCommandLineInfo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/mfc/reference/ccommandlineinfo-class) makes those assumptions for you (which you cannot change). If you want to provide a custom command line interface, you're going to have to implement a parser for that, either by hand or by using a pre-built solution like [docopt](https://github.com/docopt/docopt.cpp) or [cxxopts](https://github.com/jarro2783/cxxopts).